Is this property of asymptotic functions correct?
I'm learning math on my own, and I want some clarification on asymptotes.
Given a real continuous function $f$ with a domain containing all natural numbers, and a range in the set of all real numbers, if we define $f$ as
$f(x) > 1$
$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$
And define a constant, c, where
$c > 1$
Can we prove there are finite points where
$f(x) > c$
in the region $[0, \infty)$?
I think this is correct, because otherwise there would be infinite counterexamples, meaning our original limit is incorrect and we would have to define a limit superior and inferior instead.
EDIT: Changed my question to concern a natural domain instead if a real domain.

Absolutely not. In point of fact, for all $f$ continuous and $c\in\Bbb R$, ${x\in[0,\infty),:, f(x)>c}$ is either empty or in bijection with $\Bbb R$.

Can you clarify what you mean by "there are finite points where $f(x)>c$"? Do you mean there are finitely many such points? Do you mean the set of such points is bounded? Do you mean there exists a finite value $x$ such that $f(x)>c$?

Your wording is unclear.  "There are finitely many points $x$ where $f(x)>c$" is false.  "The set of $x$ where $f(x)>c$ has finite measure" is true.

@Sassatelli how about when the domain is only natural numbers? Also thank you for the response.

@ENUM Then yes, it's apparent from the definition.

As @SassatelliGiulio pointed out, if the domain is real, then the set of points where $f(x) > c$ is either empty or in bijection with the set of real numbers.
As for a natural domain, or any domain within a countable infinity, then the set of points where $f(x) > c$ has to be finite in length, or else the limit is incorrect.
